# Very long reception times for web assets with same size

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-devtools

I've got a web application which using JS loads some assets from a remote server. I've got a strange issue where the reception back of some calls is very long - though it has the same size as others.

What could be the reason? Any techniques to find out?

Here is an example of the calls:

[image]

You can see the last and first call - the actual content is almost the same size, but the reception time of the last call is MUCH larger than the first one (1.3 min vs 36 sec)

P.S - the calls go to the SAME endpoint on the same server (just other params)

Thanks!

Comment: is there any performance issue on the remote resource? try loading it directly on the browser

Comment: doesn't seem to be a performance issue - but this is consistent. That last call always takes this long time to receive - though it has the same content size as the first call. Can it be that server responds with an OK and waits before sending the answer?

Comment: it doesn't make sense to me when a static resource takes > 10s, furthermore 1.3min

Comment: This is not a static resource - rather an API call to a server. But I would expect that the waiting time to be long (before the server would answer) and when the server answers, the reception itself should as quick as the first call.

Comment: Is there any breakpoint in devtools? The translucent bar that you are seeing is actually chrome already connected to the server and waiting for the server to respond, from the image, it's a good 30 seconds? Even if it's a calculation intensive but asynchronous call, it's going to kill the server if there's high concurrency

Comment: For the server it's OK - it is very intensive and should take this long (20-30 sec). I'm wondering about the opaque bar - as it's way too long...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the clarifications & your acknowledgement of ~30 seconds of processing time being "normal" and "accepted". The likely reason is because your web server is flushing the output buffer.

Some useful information:

### PHP

[php flush](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php)

### IIS

[Can I Flush the Buffer Early Using ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678811/can-i-flush-the-buffer-early-using-asp-net)

Some background info:

> When users request a page, it can take anywhere from 200 to 500ms for
>   the backend server to stitch together the HTML page. During this time,
>   the browser is idle as it waits for the data to arrive. In PHP you
>   have the function flush(). It allows you to send your partially ready
>   HTML response to the browser so that the browser can start fetching
>   components while your backend is busy with the rest of the HTML page.
>   The benefit is mainly seen on busy backends or light frontends.

Technically, it's better for your web server to flush them as soon as possible, firstly, you free up memory, secondly, the client (browser in this case) can start rendering with the chunks of data.

Comment: Yep - that was it. The server was flushing a first small response and only after a long time the full response, thus it sent the "ACK" very early - before the real response was sent